# Beaglebone Debian/jessie autoinit script

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

I am trying to make my script initialize with beaglebone in the boot process. For that, I use systemctl initialization process.

My service is placed in `/lib/systemctl/system` with the name autostart-scripts.service and the content is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Autostart Scripts

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/init-usb-internet.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see my script is placed in hokme and its content is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Autoconfiguring internet on micro USB connection"
echo "Setting up the default gateway"
/sbin/route add default gw 192.168.7.1

echo "Updating the nameserver entry"
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf

echo "Setting the time using the Irish ntp pool"
/usr/bin/ntpdate -b -s -u ie.pool.ntp.org
```

And it is not working, I follow the steps registering the service in systemctl with enable but for some reason it has problem in the execution at begining.

The systemctl status is this:

```
● autostart-scripts.service - Autostart Scripts
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autostart-scripts.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-02-21 16:26:43 UTC; 7min ago
  Process: 852 ExecStart=/home/init-usb-internet.sh (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 852 (code=exited, status=127)

Feb 21 16:26:42 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[852]: Autoconfiguring internet on micro USB connection
Feb 21 16:26:42 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[852]: Setting up the default gateway
Feb 21 16:26:42 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[852]: SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
Feb 21 16:26:42 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[852]: Updating the nameserver entry
Feb 21 16:26:42 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[852]: Setting the time using the Irish ntp pool
Feb 21 16:26:42 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[852]: /home/init-usb-internet.sh: 10: /home/init-usb-internet.sh: /usr/bin/ntpda
Feb 21 16:26:43 beaglebone systemd[1]: autostart-scripts.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Feb 21 16:26:43 beaglebone systemd[1]: Failed to start Autostart Scripts.
Feb 21 16:26:43 beaglebone systemd[1]: autostart-scripts.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 21 16:26:43 beaglebone systemd[1]: autostart-scripts.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Update 1:**

I remove synchronization time command and add After=network-online.target in [Unit] section and the problem still existing. The new status is this, I think problem is related to network communication. Probably it is executing first than other important network service.

```
[sudo] password for debian:
● autostart-scripts.service - Autostart Scripts
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autostart-scripts.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-02-22 10:06:07 UTC; 1min 36s ago
  Process: 947 ExecStart=/home/init-usb-internet.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 947 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 22 10:06:07 beaglebone systemd[1]: Starting Autostart Scripts...
Feb 22 10:06:07 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[947]: Autoconfiguring internet on micro USB connection
Feb 22 10:06:07 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[947]: Setting up the default gateway
Feb 22 10:06:07 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[947]: SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
Feb 22 10:06:07 beaglebone init-usb-internet.sh[947]: Updating the nameserver entry
Feb 22 10:06:07 beaglebone systemd[1]: Started Autostart Scripts.
```

Comment: Try adding in the `[Unit]` part `After=network-online.target`

Comment: Didn't work. Also I remove synchronization time command and problem still existing.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve!

There were 3 problems in my work.

1st [critical=low] The folder for ntpdate was not correct, hence my sh script got a error in this line, I removed that and I will search for the correct folder and I will test again for time auto synchronization time on booting.

2nd [critical=high] I did not specify a Type field in [Service], hence systemd was assuming the Type=simple which is not correct for my task. I need that my script execute after all the peripherals, services and targets and for that I need to specify with Type=idle.

3rd [critical=high] As I need network communication for my script I need to add After=network.service in [Unit].

Also I give execution permission and make a daemon-reload. and now it is working. I am attaching the working service code.

```
[Unit]
Description=Autostart Scripts
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/init-usb-internet.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```